# label.BackColor.Name to variable?

Tags: c#

How can i save current label color (`label.BackColor.Name`) into variable, for later retrieval? Convert it to string? If so, how? My code:

```
label.BackColor = random_Color; // Sets new color
Color previous_Color = label.BackColor.Name // Don't work
```

Comment: You could try [learning C#](http://www.learncs.org/) and [reading the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx).

Comment: "Don't work" isn't much to go on, regardless of how obvious the problem is. If there is an error message then you should let us know what the message is and where. And no, it doesn't help to tell us it's on line 42.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Color previous_Color = label.BackColor.`

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that `.Name` part is required. Back to the book.

Comment: Or `string previousColorName = label.BackColor.Name;`.